# Android: detect driving over an ImageView with a finger?

Tags: android

With which onTouchListener Event i can detect " Driving with the finger over an ImageView"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement [View.OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html).

Then override `onTouch()` in your Activity, and in ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP, check the coordinates of the touch point from the MotionEvent to see if they are in the area covered by the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

That's conflicts principle of giving responsibility to objects. ImageView should be aware of it's touch events, not the activity or fragment.